# Golf 5 stuck when shifting between 2 and 3 gear

Tags: vw, manual-transmission, shifting, golf

While driving in 2nd gear, clutch down, try to go into 3rd (this happens like once in 30) the joystick kinda get stuck in the middle, like mid-way into the downwards 'state' as I would if I wanted to go to reverse.

I tried using as little force as possible and all-together avoid the downwards pressure but sometimes even like that it get 'stuck' in some neutral-state.

At this point if I hit the gas engine roars and RMPS go up like mad so I have to quickly swap to 2nd and try again.

It's a 2005 golf (1.6 Petrol - 170 000 kms) thats very well cared for and other then this has no issues whatsoever.

Also I'm pretty a newbie when it comes to cars but I drove two before and never had this kind of issue.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It sounds like maybe your linkage bushings are getting worn out.